# curl creating empty files when incorrect url

Tags: curl

Using curl in puppet to download a zip file from CURL.

The problem is even when the URL is not correct `curl` is creating the file which I don't want.

```
eg:
curl -o file.zip http://someurl/file.zip
```

In the above command if this URL "http://someurl/file.zip" `file.zip` is not available it will create the `file.zip` with empty data.

What I want is create file only when the URL is correct.

I tried fixing this with `-f` which means '**fail silently on server errors - no output at all**' but with this when the URL is correct it doesn't download the file.

Comment: I see no reason to believe that this has anything to do with Puppet.  You should be able to reproduce it by running the same command from an interactive shell.  Tags edited.

Comment: Yeah John you are right, nothing to do with the puppet, can reproduce from the shell. Thanks for editing the tag.